# `belongsTo()` is inconsistent in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, models, entity-relationship

I've looked everywhere for this. I find that `belongsTo()` breaks depending on how I use it. I have found a way around each error but I feel like the syntax is not consistent.

```
// Sometimes this works sometimes not...
function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}

// Sometimes this works too (and sometimes not)...
function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

// Sometimes I have to do this (but it breaks sometimes too!)...
function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User')->first();
}
```

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE 02AUG2016**

Found that I had defined both `function user()` AND `getUserAttribute()`. After removing `getUserAttribute()`, `belongsTo('User', 'user_id')` worked more consistently.

Comment: I think you don't need the `user_id` foreign key if the name of user model(table) is `user'. Laravel automatically detects it. Middle one is the right one I guess...

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes this works, sometimes not"? Any error you're getting? What is it that you want to achieve and what is it thaty you're getting?